# How is the integral relationship between current yield curve and forward yield curve derived?

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, forward-rate

$$y(\tau) = \frac{1}{\tau} \int_{0}^{\tau} du \Big(f(u)\Big)$$
As far as I understand the forward rate is the future rate based on the *expectation hypothesis*. But it is unclear how many years into the future is the forward yield curve. **Is it one year ahead?** Is the future horizon unimportant at all and the results will always be the same?

It would therefore be good to see a derivation of this relationship.